# Scraping tweets - better to use the site or api?

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, screen-scraping

I'm using the `twitter` gem to build a Twitter bot in Ruby. I am trying to make it self-sustainable as it were, so I want it to generate its own content to tweet by scraping tweets of users outside its social circle (and then perhaps garbling them with Markov chain generator).

Which one is a better strategy?

- Search for tweets via api
- Load Twitter pages and scrape tweets with `Hpricot` or `Nokogiri`

Also, how can I try to ensure the base tweets come from outside my bot's followers' friends so it's harder to tell it's a bot?

At the moment I use a `.yml` file with tweets I generated by hand, which is far from ideal.

Comment: So you want us to help you write a twitter spam bot. Good luck with that. -1

Comment: It's a little more complex than that. I'm writing a bot for my final degree project to study robot-human relationships. For the purpose of the experiment it needs to be believable for at least a week, spamming users would not help me with that.

Comment: I forgot to say that I see your point though.

Comment: Negating Rein Henrichs' -1. Most twitter spam bots don't involve artificial intelligence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two questions here.

It's always better to use an API where one is available. This will future-proof you against the bot randomly breaking if a simple html element is changed, and it will also allow the website (ie, twitter) to rate limit your searches in case you put too high a load on the service. Although this is unlikely for twitter, it's good practice.

Sometimes, the information you want is unobtainable via the API. In this case, you should consider if you really need to scrape it, and if so, how to limit yourself to be polite.

Basically, if the API allows you to do what you want, use it for maintainability.

As for your second question, I do not have any experience with the twitter API. Is there a method to get twitter IDs of all your followers, and who they follow? If not, you'll be forced to scrape as earlier mentioned - if you really do need this information.

Once you have a list of those who your followers follow, you can check if the ID of the poster of what you want to repost falls inside this set.

Would you consider retweeting for this aspect of the bot?

Comment: Hi, future-proofing is a very good point that I haven't considered. Yes, there is a way of getting IDs of all my followers, so checking the IDs of their followers is possible, though I imagine fairly time-consuming. I want to avoid retweeting, rather use the tweets as basis for generating new ones.

Comment: Yes, I see your comment explaining why. You should be able to speed pu the ID lookup with a hashmap, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to also note is performance. If you were to scrape the website, you would have to download the entire page, then scrape the page(which is processor intensive as it is). As opposed to hitting the API, which would only return JSON/XML data.

So from strictly a performance standpoint, I would go with the API.

Comment: Thanks, a very good point, though I accepted the answer which pointed out possibility of stuff breaking over time.